# Zn-Cu galvanic cell

Tags: electrochemistry

In a Zn-Cu galvanic cell, if both electrodes connected by a wire are placed in the same container with a mixture of both electrolytes, will electrons still flow through the wire?

Answer (score 1):

Of course they will. But there also will be another process we'd rather avoid: metallic Zn will start reacting with Cu electrolyte directly. That's the reason why we usually want to separate cathode and anode spaces.